# C# ASP.NET Web Service Reservation System NON-DATABASE

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, arraylist

i am having trouble with a little system of mine and as the title suggests i am utilizing ASP.NET and C# programming technologies. In particular, web services and array lists.

Alternatively i have been told i can use a cache object to store the array list or something but i have no idea how to do these.

Everything on my project is fine when i run it locally but i cant seem to get it to even run the web service.

How my program works is the user reserves a Seat Number in a Row and supplies the name for the reservation to be under. The data is passed along in a string

```
 "Seat Number " + seatNumber + " In Row Number " + rowNumber + " Is Reserved";
```

and then it is added to the array list. The output will look something like this:
Seat Number 5 In Row Number 4 Is Reserved. Duplicate entries are easy to prevent but when i try this on the web service, i dont think any data passes across.

When a seat is reserved, the following code is executed:

```
// Retrieve the values from the form controls
string seat = boxSeat.Text;
string row = boxRow.Text;
string name = txtName.Text;

// Convert form control values for Row and Seat into integers
int Row2 = Convert.ToInt32(row);
int Seat2 = Convert.ToInt32(seat);

// Generate Reservation Request
var req = new ReservationRequest();
// Pass the form control values to the request
req.Row = Row2;
req.Seat = Seat2;
req.Name = name;
var resp = new ReservationResponse();

// Create SOAP client
var client = new ReservationsSoapClient();
```

The classes `ReservationRequest` and `ReservationResponse` hold the data to be passed and the confirmation message respectively.

This is the code from my web service

```
[WebMethod]
public ReserveSeatResponse ReserveSeat(ReserveSeatRequest req)
{
    var resp = new ReserveSeatResponse();
    int rowNumber = req.Row;
    int seatNumber = req.Seat;
    string name = req.Name;
    string message;
    string seat = "Seat Number " + seatNumber + " In ";
    string row = "Row Number " + rowNumber;
    string booking = seat;
    booking += row;
    message = "Congratulations! " + booking + " is reserved by " + req.Name;
    reservations.Add(booking);
    resp.confirmation = message;
    return resp;
```

This code is supposed to retrieve the Row and Seat numbers, as well as the reservation name from the `ReservationRequest` class, then place it in a "booking" string and add that to the array. I don't care about duplicates at the moment as I want to get it to work.

I added into the form a `messagebox.show(resp.confirmation);` line of code to print the confirmation message but everything I tried just gave me blank.

I would really appreciate some help and if i need to put any more code or anything just comment and i will supply it. Its just really annoying

ALSO if someone could recommend a caching object tutorial in C# to do with webservices and arrays or give me some advice on how to do that or just whether to use an ArrayList or a Generic List I would sincerely appreciate that.

Thank you very much

Comment: are you trying to persist your reservations within the web service without a database? You are probalby going to need some method of persistence that survives recycling the application pool of your web server. In addition, please supply the client code that actually calls the web service. The code you posted only shows how you create the calling parameter and the web service client, but you don't actually call anything.

Comment: Yeah, im trying to post the reservation data to the webservice and the webservice adds the data into an ArrayList or a List. From there i should be able to check whether there is a duplicate entry in the array. The first block of code is triggered by a button click event because im using a windows form application to consume the web service

Comment: ok, please add the code that calls your web service method from your winforms client (i assume it is winforms as you mentioned MessageBox.Show). While your arraylist won't be the right method to store persistent data, at least the return value from a web service call should contain the confirmation message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox, use Firebug to identify the issue or if you have fiddler installed on your machine, you can use it as well.

In Firebug check the requests being sent to the web service and see what it is sending back in the response.

Comment: I have determined that after 2 days of fiddling i have managed to get it to work locally 100% however i cannot link the Request and Responses classes located in the ASP.NET Black Web Site project to my windows form client which is to consume the web service. it is my only problem

Comment: Sorry couldn't understand your problem, can you illustrate it a little bit or its better if you start a new question for it, if incase I can't help out in it, someone else might.